# How to append data from ajax call to a div inside ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from ajax to a div  in the same page, I have failed to get data from ajax, it might be the div that I want to get data inside it, however it is a child for li and li is a child for ul,
so how can I solve it ?

here is HTML code

```
<li>
    <ul class="notificationsbtn nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="notificationsli">
            <a id="test" name="@currentUser.Id" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></small>
                @*@if (@Model.Where(n => n.IsRead == false).Any())*@
                @*{*@<span class="noty-manager-bubble" style="margin-left:0px; top: 10px; opacity: 1;">@*@Model.Where(n => n.IsRead == false).Count()*@10</span>@*}*@
            </a>
            <div id="notification-container" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                <section class="panel">
                    <header class="panel-heading">
                        <strong>The Notification</strong>
                    </header>
                    <div id="notification-list">
                        @*@await Component.InvokeAsync("Notification")*@
                        <div style="float:left;margin-top:20px" class="loader"></div>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="panel-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                        <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Notifications" asp-route-id="@currentUser.Id" class="text-success h5" data-toggle="class:show animated fadeInRight"><span style="margin-left:0px; top: 5px; opacity: 1;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> all notifications</a>
                    </footer>
                </section>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and jquery(ajax) code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').click(function () {
        {
            alert("ssss");
            //$("#notification-list").empty();
            var _url = '@Url.Action("GetMyViewCompNotification", "Home")';
            $(".loader").fadeIn();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: _url,
                data: { uid: $(this).prop("name") },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#notification-list").html(result);
                    alert("success")
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    alert(err.toString(), 'Error - LoadListItemsHelper');
                },
                complete: function (result, jqXHR, status) {
                    $(".loader").fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

action code in the controller:

```
 public  IActionResult GetMyViewCompNotification(string uid)
    {
        return ViewComponent("Notification", new { id = uid });//it will call Follower.cs InvokeAsync, and pass id to it.
    }
```

Comment: Can you please send mvc action code in action return HTML? or json

Comment: public  IActionResult GetMyViewCompNotification(string uid)
        {
            return ViewComponent("Notification", new { id = uid });//it will call Follower.cs InvokeAsync, and pass id to it.
        }

Comment: it returns view component

Comment: So here you are returning the view and assign in `notification-list` it's correct?

Comment: Just change this `$("#notification-list").html(result);` to `$("#notification-list").append(result);`

Comment: yes you are right...

Comment: @mohammedalani1991 Please don't post code in the comment section but edit your question.

Comment: ok... i will add action in question section...i am new in this community sorry for that...i have tried append method before and it does not work

Comment: What do you get with `success: function (result) { console.log(result); }` and what do you get with `success: function (result) { console.log($("#notification-list").length, $("[id="notification-list"]).length) }` ? *Or* what error do you get in your `error:` handler?  Include the `status`

Comment: @freedomn-m i got the result (list of notification) when in append it inside another div , but the problem happening only when i append data in the mentioned div , so the problem is not with ajax or returned data, the problem is with the appending the returned data inside the specified div

Comment: You should consider adding a [mcve] snippet.  If your return from ajax is fine, then remove the ajax from the question as it just confuses issues (such as asking for the mvc action)

Comment: Ok, so it's not the `result` that that's the issue, but still, what do you get with `console.log($("#notification-list").length, $("[id="notification-list"]).length)` ?  Ideally within `success:` callback

Comment: i got (1) when i used `alert($('#notification-list').length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, ajax function was not append data to the specified div because of the id ("notification-list") , when i changed the id to ("testn") i got the data

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#test').click(function () {
                {
                    //$("#notification-list").empty();
                    var _url = '@Url.Action("GetMyViewCompNotification", "Home")';
                    $(".loader").fadeIn();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: _url,
                        data: { uid: $(this).prop("name") },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $(".testn").html(result);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                            alert(err.toString(), 'Error - LoadListItemsHelper');
                        },
                        complete: function (result, jqXHR, status) {
                            $(".loader").fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```